# To Replace Numerical Values in a certain column with other Numerical Values

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have data as below:

```
83997000|17561815|20370101000000 83997000|3585618|20370101000000 
83941746|13898890|20361231230000 83940169|13842974|20171124205011 
83999444|3585618|20370101000000 83943970|10560874|20370101000000 
83942000|13898890|20371232230000 83999333|3585618|20350101120000
```

Now, what I want to achieve is as below:

If column 2 is `17561815`, print `22220` to replace `17561815`.

If column 2 is `3585618`, print `23330` to replace `3585618`.

If column 2 is `13898890`, print `24440` to replace `13898890`.

If column 2 is `13842974`, print `25550` to replace `13842974`.

If column 2 is `3585618`, print `26660` to replace `3585618`.

If column 2 is `10560874`, print `27770` to replace `10560874`.

Output to be like this:

```
83997000|22220|20370101000000 83997000|23330|20370101000000 
83941746|24440|20361231230000 83940169|25550|20171124205011 
83999444|26660|20370101000000 83943970|27770|20370101000000 
83942000|24440|20371232230000 83999333|26660|20350101120000
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show us what you have done and people will be more inclined to help you. we aren't going to do your work/homework for you.

Comment: What number should replace 3585618, 23330 or 26660?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, I have just started to learn Linux. I'm improving

Comment: @choroba, sorry. 26660 is meant to replace 3585618 all through

Answer (score 3):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         FS=OFS="|"; 
         a["17561815"]=22220; a["13898890"]=24440; 
         a["3585618"]=26660; a["13842974"]=25550; 
         a["10560874"]=27770 
     }
     $2 in a{ $2=a[$2] }
     $4 in a{ $4=a[$4] }1' file
```

The output:

```
83997000|22220|20370101000000 83997000|26660|20370101000000 
83941746|24440|20361231230000 83940169|25550|20171124205011 
83999444|26660|20370101000000 83943970|27770|20370101000000 
83942000|24440|20371232230000 83999333|26660|20350101120000
```

Comment: Where does the question mention column 4?

Comment: @ghoti, don't try to understand, that's the case of intuition and "reading thoughts" )

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks a lot. Your reply was useful. However, there should have been only 3 columns in what I posted. The page re-formatted it into 6 columns. So now, I worked with only 3 columns and thereby adjusted the commands to look like this:                          
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         FS=OFS="|"; 
         a["17561815"]=22220; a["13898890"]=24440; 
         a["3585618"]=26660; a["13842974"]=25550; 
         a["10560874"]=27770 
     }
     $2 in a{ $2=a[$2] }1' file